# React global component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, create-react-app

I am coming from a vue.js background and I have just recently started looking into react.

I have a component: PageContent.jsx and I wish to use it without constantly having to import it to be able to use it inside the render function (JSX).

In vue it is possible to globalise a component using:

```
Vue.component(componentName, componentObject)
```

Is there anything similar in react?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, there isn't any kind of "global" component in React. Each component has to be imported or passed as a prop. You have a few options if you want to avoid adding an import to each file though:

1) Create a [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that renders the `PageContent` and the wrapped component.

```
import PageContent from './PageContent';

const withPageContent = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <PageContent>
          <WrappedComponent />
        </PageContent>
      )
    }
  }
};

export default withPageContent;

// Usage

import withPageContent from './withPageContent';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        I'm wrapped in PageContent!
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withPageContent(MyComponent);
```

2) Pass `PageContent` as a prop to a component:

```
import PageContent from './PageContent';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Child1 content={PageContent} />
        <Child2 content={PageContent} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

// Usage

export default class Child1 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const PageContent = this.props.content;
    return (
      <PageContent>
        I'm wrapped in PageContent!
      </PageContent>
    )
  }
}

export default class Child2 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const PageContent = this.props.content;
    return (
      <PageContent>
        I'm wrapped in PageContent!
      </PageContent>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, though I was really looking for something to cut back the amount of imports necessary for each component. It seems like I have to live with that though if I want to work with react

Comment: Yeah you will still have to import something, but there are a few tricks you can do to make it easier on you. You can use [webpack resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) to make your import paths much smaller and remove file extensions. You can also create a single file that exports multiple components, and then you can import multiple components on one line like so: `import { Button, Input, Icon } from 'utils/inputs';`

Answer (score 4):

I very much agree with [Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535040/chase-deanda)'s answer.
Still if you need another approach you can use the [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You can declare in the App root, or another nested components tree, a collection of components that you want to easily access.

Here is an example with the `useContext` hook, but hooks is not a must. The structure is the standard `create-react-app` structure.

The component we would like to access globally - *src/deep/Header.js*:

```js
function Header() {
  return (
    <h1>
      I am a global component
    </h1>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

The context creation - *src/global-components-context.js*:

```js
import React from 'react';

const MyContext = React.createContext(null);

export default MyContext;
```

The grouping of the global-components - *src/global-components.js*:

```js
import Header from './deep/Header';

const contextValue = {
  Header,
};

export default contextValue;
```

The app init file - *src/index.js*:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import MyContext from './global-components-context';
import contextValue from './global-component';

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
    <App />
  </MyContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Using the component without importing it - *src/App.js*:

```js
import { useContext } from 'react';
import globalComponent from './global-components-context';

function App() {
  const Context = useContext(globalComponent);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Context.Header />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I think this is the most global components you can have in react. Note that you still need to import the context wherever you would like to use a global component.

Also one more disclaimer, global components are very hard to test and often to reason about. I believe that is why there is no standard solution for it in react.

Hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: use *Zustand* global state management library as in the following example:
 https://snack.expo.dev/3yNFvhCmI?platform=web

---

## Solution

There are two main ways this could be accomplished:

- **Context API** — the Context API is a built-in feature in React that provides a simple way to share state across components,
- **State management libraries** — third-party libraries like *Redux*, *MobX*, or *[Zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand)* for managing the state globally.

While the Context API solution is relatively simple and doesn't require any additional dependencies, it can lead to unnecessary re-renders and comes with a penalty of some boilerplate code.

Considering these factors and more, it may be beneficial to opt for a dedicated state management library in this scenario. Personally, I would advise against using *Redux* for this due to its heavy footprint, complexity, boilerplate nature, and potential impact on performance. This is especially true for smaller projects, where *Redux* would be an overkill.

---

## Demos

Two working examples showcasing an identical use case with two React Native modals:
<sup>(React Native is used here just because that's what I work with at the moment; this can be easily refactored for React)</sup>

- **Context API**: https://snack.expo.dev/EEbnxTHfR?platform=web
- **Zustand**: https://snack.expo.dev/3yNFvhCmI?platform=web

---

## Step-by-step description of the `Context` API way

“*Talk is cheap. Show me the code.*”:

**1. Project structure:**

```
- src
  - components
    - global
      - GlobalComponent1.js
      - GlobalComponent2.js
      - index.js
  - contexts
    - GlobalComponentsContext.js
  - screens
    - HomeScreen.js
- App.js
```

**2. Fundaments:**

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const GlobalComponentsContext = createContext();

export const GlobalComponentsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const globalState = {};

  [ globalState.value1, globalState.setValue1 ] = useState(false);
  [ globalState.value2, globalState.setValue2 ] = useState(false);

  return (
    <GlobalComponentsContext.Provider value={ globalState }>
      { children }
    </GlobalComponentsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**3. A sample global component:**

```
import { GlobalComponentsContext } from '../../contexts/GlobalComponentsContext';

const GlobalComponent1 = () => {
  // accessing the global state; drop-in replacement for useState()
  const { value1, setValue1 } = useContext(GlobalComponentsContext);

  [...]
};

export default GlobalComponent1;
```

**4. Wrap the `App` with the `Context.Provider`:**

```
import { GlobalComponentsProvider } from './src/contexts/GlobalComponentsContext';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import GlobalComponents from './src/components/global';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalComponentsProvider>
      <HomeScreen />
      <GlobalComponents />
    </GlobalComponentsProvider>
  )
}
```

**5. Sample use of a global component:**

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { GlobalComponentsContext } from '../contexts/GlobalComponentsContext';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  // Take the state variables that you need:
  const { value1, setValue2 } = useContext(GlobalComponentsContext);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Value1: {value1}</Text>
      <Button title="setValue2" onPress={() => setValue2(true)} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```