# Globally importing react rather than importing in each component [React Hooks]

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering if there is a way to provide React globally rather than importing it in each component

I have tried configuring my webpack.config.js with a provider function but it doesn't seem to work.

Webpack code

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     'React':     'react'
   })
],
```

It would be great to have a suggestion for this as it gets a bit redundant to import it in each component.

Comment: If you  use `create-react-app` it will be automatically initialized globally you don't have to edit `webpack.config`

Comment: @theWellHopeErr Actually I am using nextjs is there any way to configure in this ?

Answer (score 1):

In React, there is no global importing but we can avoid importing `react` in every file by these two indirect methods.

1. Creating a Higher Order Component and wrapping your other components within it.
2. Passing the components as a prop.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50995813/8826642) for more details and an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new plugin in ***webpack.config.js*** :

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react',
    }),
  ]
```

Also if you are using TypeScript you should add this in ***tsconfig.json*** :

```
 "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true
```